# Using OR in a SQL statement giving 'undefined variable' error in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm grabbing a count stat (`$hits`) from the following sql statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS hits FROM users 
    WHERE password = :password
    AND username = :username
```

Grabbing the variable in a `while()` loop here works fine, it's not untill I try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS hits FROM users 
    WHERE password = :password
    AND (username = :username OR email = :username)
```

that I get an 'undifined variable' error when I try pull 'hits' as `$hits = $row['hits'];`

I want a user to be able to log in using a username or email address. Can anyone tell me why the first SQL statement works fine but the second does not?

My PHP is as follows:

```
// COUNT HITS
$COUNT_HITS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS hits FROM users WHERE password = :password AND (username = :username OR email = :username)");
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':password', $password);
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':username', $username);
$COUNT_HITS->execute();
while($row = $COUNT_HITS->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $hits= $row['hits'];
}
```

Comment: I've tried the second statement in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and replaced the variables, it returns a value for `hits`. Does PHP not like the double use of `:username` in the second statement?

Comment: you might have to bind it twice - share your php please.

Comment: @DanielA.White yes it is as so: `while($row = $COUNT_HITS->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){}`

Comment: `$DBH` is defined in a separate connection file

Comment: *"that I get an 'undifined variable' error"* - Please give the full/actual error, copy/paste the real error. SQL doesn't write out `undifined`.

Comment: What about just echoing $rows["hits"] for a try ?

Comment: And i'll go for something like this :
`$COUNT_HITS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS hits FROM users WHERE password = :password AND (username = :username OR email = :email)");

$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':password', $password);
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':username', $username);
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':email', $username);
`
but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code; *tested*. Result: `1`. Add `$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. That will show you the real error. Maybe even error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Stv please do not dump code into comments.

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry, i dumped the code because i've not judged this as an answer.

Comment: @Stv your suggestion has solved the issue, `$hits` is now valued as required. It seems that the double `:username` was the issue

Comment: @Stv please repost your comment as an answer, your solution was made available first, thus you deserve the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Look here:

> username = **:username** OR email = **:username**

You can do this in PDO, not by default at least

**Solution**

Add a third params

> username = **:username** OR email = **:username_email**

and bind to the same `$username` value, that's okay.

```
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':password', $password);
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':username', $username);
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':username_email', $username);
$COUNT_HITS->execute();
```

Comment: I tested OP's code as is, and it worked fine for me. I think the problem is with the table.

Comment: Problem can be resolved using this answer although a solution was posted earlier as a comment. I'm giving @Stv a chance to post as answer, if this doesn't happen I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @fred -ii- i believe you have turned on emulation, does not work with default

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here a proper answer :

```
$COUNT_HITS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS hits FROM users WHERE password = :password AND (username = :username OR email = :email)"); 
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':password', $password);
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':username', $username);
$COUNT_HITS->bindParam(':email', $username);
```

Hope this works.